# show loader with fromEvent input keyup in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to load progress-bar when input has value. These code working only once, after subscribing progress-bar value is false, process does not start over. I want to cycle this process.

```js
    bar: boolean = false;


    fromEvent(this.model.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
     tap(() => this.bar = true),
      debounceTime(2000),
      pluck('target','value'),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((res:any) => {
        return iif(() => res.length >= 3, this.carService.getCars(res))}
      ),
     finalize(() => this.bar = false)
    ).subscribe((res:any) => {
      this.carsList = res.Results;
    })}
```

HTML

```html
    <div *ngIf="bar">
      <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? Because if the finalize is being called, then it means that that observable has stopped listening

Comment: Wouldn't filter before the switchMap be better than iff?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is fine, it could be that your observable is throwing some errors, or completing for some reason. The from event shoulnd't complete, so the finalize wouldn't be called until you complete it.

I am not sure what is your end goal, but maybe you should set the bar to false once you get the result from your car service.

Another thing that could be the issue is your IIF, you need to provide the else observable.

Here is a quick example

```
const h1 = document.getElementById("example")
fromEvent(h1, "click").pipe(
  tap(()=>console.log("BARTRUE"))    ,
  switchMap(()=>of("DONE").pipe(delay(3000), tap(()=>console.log("BARFALSE")))),
  finalize(()=>{console.log("FINALIZED")})
).subscribe(
  r=>{
    console.log(variable)
  }
)
```